# I cant access/load CSS, JS and Image CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I migrated my website into CI. Follow what's happenin':

Well, this is the error that shows when i click in the link css

[image: HTML]

When i click in any link above shows:

[image: 404]

so, The CI cant found the css, js code and the images! Nothing!

My Folder Structure

[image]

The folder "Site" is the website that i migrated for CI ok? so I took all css, js and image and I've created a folder public and put together "applications, system"

My Controller that call the website

> Site.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('site/index');
    }
}
```

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|public)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I think that the error is the .htaccess, but my knowledge dont show me a output!

Comment: Where is your `index.php` file?

Comment: Just looking at your file structure, your links say localhost/alumegas/css/{file}.css when they need to say localhost/alumegas/public/css/{file}.css, otherwise you're linking to nowhere.

Comment: It looks to me that your css path is `alumegas/public/css`, you've no htaccess rules that routes css to public folder

Comment: WoW! Well done guys, really i forgot /public/!